# Install Magento2 using different MySQL port

Tags: mysql, magento2, installation, magento2-dev-beta

I have MySQL server running on a different port than the default one.

Suppose, the default port for MySQL is 3306. I have another MySQL server running on port 5625. I want to install Magento2 using MySQL database from port 5625.

While installing Magento2, I can only specify hostname, username, password and database name.

How can I specify port number as well at the time of installation?

Comment: please visit the link to get solution:-1)https://gist.github.com/DirtyF/c42d87cea2bdc419c474             2)http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/magento-2-installation-guide/

Comment: @AshvinMonpara: I think the docker tutorial link is telling about HTTP port, not the MySQL port.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the CLI, you can append the port to the --db-host flag. You can probably do the same thing in the Setup Wizard.

IOW, --db-host=localhost:5625

Answer (score 1):

If you're using docker; make sure to not use localhost as given. - Use the container name such as 'mysql'. - So when you're in the setup just give it your container name.

Answer (score 0):

Magento takes default database port to *3306*. In case of the *port 3306* used by any other application and mySQL is running on another port then we can use that new port by passing port number with the database host.

```
--db:host=127.0.0.1:3307
```

Here ***3307*** is a port which bind with the MySQL.

So, a full command will be to install the Magento:

```
php bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=https://magento244.test \
--db-host=127.0.0.1:3307 \
--db-name=magento2 \
--db-user=root \
--db-password=root \
--admin-firstname=Mage \
--admin-lastname=Smoker \
--admin-email=naveenos@xxxx.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 \
--elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com \
--elasticsearch-port=9200 \
--elasticsearch-index-prefix=magento2 \
--elasticsearch-timeout=15
```

If you getting error to run above command then you can put in a single line and install to:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=https://magento244.test --db-host=127.0.0.1:3307 --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=root --admin-firstname=Mage --admin-lastname=Smoker --admin-email=naveenos@xyz.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com --elasticsearch-port=9200 --elasticsearch-index-prefix=magento2 --elasticsearch-timeout=15
```